# Eclipse maven | lambda | use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, expressões-lambda, jdk

Projeto Java Maven no Eclipse neon (4.6.0), simplesmente não compila ao utilizar lambda.

O erro:

> use lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 8
>   or higher to enable lambda expressions)

O detalhe é que estou usando o JDK 8:

> *java version "1.8.0_101" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)*

O Eclipse também está configurado corretamente conforme imagens abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguma ideia do motivo de estar dando erro de lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código do seu `pom.xml` também deve referenciar o java8. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas eu nunca tinha precisado fazer isso, sabe o motivo? Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, toda vez que você faz build do projeto maven ele troca a versão do java que você tinha selecionado. Por isso você precisa sempre informar isso no pom.